# Localytics Flow is not being logged properly on the server in my Android app

Tags: android, analytics, localytics

I am working on an android app where I am supposed to log the flow in the Localytics(same like google analytics); that means how a user is walking through in my app. But flow in my app seems to be behaving weird because there are few Activities which can never be reached by certain Activities. But this flow is being logged in the Localytics. I followed the documentation accurately and events are being logged in fine.
I am writing these 3 lines of code in every activity's onResume() method as documentation says

```
onResume() 
{
   super.onResume();
   Localytics.openSession();
   Localytics.tagScreen("Splash");
   Localytics.upload();
}
```

Now I have a couple of questions about these line of codes.
1. Is it the right approach to write `Localytics.openSession();` in EVERY activity's onResume() method OR it should ONLY BE CALLED ONCE in the Splash activity?
2. Do I have to write `Localytics.closeSession();` a method in every activity, for the Localytics to work properly?
3. Where can I find detailed information about what these methods do and how? Because There is not enough information in the API section of this Website(www.localytics.com).

```
My main concern and the priority is to make sure the flow of activities should be logged properly. So if someone has faced the same problem and found a working solution. Please share it here.
```